# Почему 2 байта 105,135 System::BitConverter::ToUInt16() даёт 34665 вместо 27015?

Tags: c#, .net

Пробовал конвертировать онлайн конвертерами 27015 в десятичное, получал 15 байт, добавил 0 в к позиции 0, получил 16. Разделил 16 байт на 2 по 8, получилось

```
27015 это
01101001 d10=105
10000111 d10=135
а .NetF (ToUInt16) из этого делает не 27015, а 34665
            
cli::array<unsigned char> ^arrBytesCurrentDbg2 = gcnew cli::array<unsigned char>{(char)105, (char)135};     
unsigned short int16DbgCurrent2 = System::BitConverter::ToUInt16(arrBytesCurrentDbg2,0);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, приведите в вопросе свой точный код. Во-вторых, подсказка, `105 * 256 + 135 = 27015`, а `135 * 256 + 105 = 34665`.

Comment: Видимо у Microsoft в .NetF не исправленная ошибка уже годов 15, на их сайте в песочнице получается та же ошибка https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint16?view=netframework-4.6.1#code-try-2

Comment: Это не ошибка, это так и задумано.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Answer (score 3):

BitConverter использует так называемый host byte order, то есть порядок байт соответствующий архитектуре процессора.

Процессоры архитектур x86, amd64 и arm (то есть все популярные) относятся к остроконечникам (little-endian), что означает что они используют порядок разрядов от младшего к старшему.

Именно поэтому преобразование пары байт [x, y] в число происходит по правилу `x + y * 256`, а не `x * 256 + y` как вы подумали. Но вот если запустить ваш код на мейнфрейме от IBM, то он сработает именно так как вы планировали изначально.

Проверить порядок байт платформы можно обращением к полю `System::BitConverter::IsLittleEndian`.

Comment: `BitConverter` не рекомендуют использовать из-за его такого поведения. Рекомендуется использовать [BinaryPrimitives](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives).